# Unidentified bright-green long-leaf plant? TX

Tags: identification, urban-gardening

This was outside just noticed it growing. Long waxy leaves, bright green, and seems to come from a very solid base. It's growing really close to a tree in a cluster of 4.

[image: leaves, waxy, green]

[image: long leaves]

[image: base]

[image: cluster]

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Hymenocallis speciosa, but I am not certain.

Comment: I don't think that's it. The base looks different and I'm not sure that it flowers.

Comment: Ah. Perhaps Doryanthes?

Comment: Cardiocrinum? May be a possibility am not sure

Comment: Definitly not Cardiocrinum. @Rosie

Comment: Doryanthes is closer... but the leaves aren't as upright.. and I don't think it gets that big. @Viv

Comment: Crinum pedunculatum?

Comment: @Viv YES! The pictures of the young ones look exactly like that! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

allium variety could be a possibilty

Comment: Welcome to G&L. Care to share why you think so.